# Does Windows 7 uses all this memory while doing nothing?

Tags: windows-7, memory

I have a fresh installation of Windows 7 on my pc. The pc is not new, but now it's super slow. Also, now the fan is always making noise. I think I've installed all the drivers.
I don't think that I have some hardware issue, since I was using Debian and it was running just fine.
I don't know what to do to make it faster. Even when I'm just using facebook/youtube it "freezes" sometimes.

There are some screenshots:

[image: Processes]

[image: Performance]

[image: Configuration]
Thanks in advance.

@edit
[image]

Comment: Im sorry. Please check my edit @Jedi

Comment: @Jedi  i've often found the processes don't add up, e.g. they add to 4GB when i'm using 14GB

Comment: @Jedi  it's also very common that svchost.exe is not using that much, and still lots of RAM is used. My system now for example.  http://i.imgur.com/7CYnPye.png  and http://i.imgur.com/IAxljO3.png   So to assume svchost for any such case of unaccounted RAM, is jumping to a conclusion prematurely.

Comment: I recommend disabling the Windows Update service entirely. You can then enable it once a week to check for updates. This can take a lot of time (days, even), because Windows Update on 7 is somehow broken.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this is a fresh installation (which it looks to be as you don't even have SP1 installed) it is most likely using CPU cycles to query and build your Windows update list. On task manager, processes tab, click "show processes for all users." Most likely you will see svchost.exe (one of them) with high CPU and RAM usage.

I do a few fresh installs a week and this is typical behavior. Lately it seems that the process is much slower than it used to be as far as Windows "finding" updates. I've had a few computers take 6+ hours to find the first few batches of updates after a fresh install.

**EDIT:**

I see you added a full process list and as expected... svchost.exe.

This is in fact Windows update actively looking for updates. Once you get them all installed it should return to normal.

Comment: -1  you don't know that, until they open task manager and see svchost using as much RAM as to explain the high ram usage.

Comment: You're right, but he has since added an additional image showing the suspected process so this proves my theory.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

This is the Windows Update service which scans for new updates. Microsoft tries to fix it with several updates.

Install this update to fix it:

**Windows Update Client for Windows 7: March 2016**
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3138612

Before trying to install the MSU, [stop the Windows Update service](https://superuser.com/a/1062876/174557) (`net stop wuauserv` from admin cmd.exe or via services.msc) to avoid a hang during setup.