# Are there real reasons to NOT upgrade Windows 7 to Windows 10?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, updates, windows-10-upgrade

Windows 10 offers some advancements over Windows 7.

Windows 10 also contains some serious disadvantages when compared to Windows 7.

Two of the most frequent complaints regarding Windows 10 are:

1. In the Home version, Microsoft can allegedly force any update on users, without any way for users to block specific unwanted updates.
2. Microsoft is allegedly collecting a significant amount of data from Windows 10 systems, without revealing *exactly* what data is being collected, and then allegedly transmitting that data outside of the user's system.

In researching these issues, I have not found any reliable solution to Issue #1.  If there is no solution (except paying more money to Microsoft for their "Pro" or "Enterprise" editions), that's a deal-breaker for many people.

For Issue #2, there seem to be quite a few third-party workarounds.  Yet in researching many of the workarounds, there are reports of unintended side-effects from using them.  Most of the workarounds do not prevent the collection of the data, only the transmission of it.  Furthermore, there are reports that the workarounds block some of the alleged data transmission to Microsoft, but ***not*** all of it.  This issue represents a deal-breaker to many people.

Issue #2 gets compounded by issue #1.  Because Microsoft can allegedly update users of Windows 10 Home at any time without their consent, Microsoft can easily circumvent any workarounds for issue #2.  Thus, allegedly, a single *behind the scenes* update of Windows 10 can immediately transmit all previously collected data outside of the user's system.

Are these issues real?

Besides these two issues, are there other real issues?

Please **avoid any opinion** in your answers and only focus on real issues that can be documented.

Comment: I hear what you are saying, but this almost seems like a rant. Even though you have brought up some topics, which may or may not be valid reasons not to upgrade, the only answers you will get here are opinions because we are not able to answer for Microsoft. Besides, the upgrade is optional, just like using Windows is optional. I'd suggest narrowing down your question so it can be answered with facts, references, or specific expertise. Speaking of references, you might want to include some certifiable research citations to validate your claims.

Comment: Windows 10 also breaks some software due to unsupported hardware.  One teen I know got his OS reverted from 10 back to 7, because 10 didn't support OpenGL on the Intel Graphics hardware of his laptop, so he was unable to play Minecraft under 10.  But it runs under 7.

Comment: @CharlieRB Thank you for your comment.  I am not interested in opinions or conjecture; I am only looking for real issues that can be clearly identified and described.  I think almost everyone is aware that Windows 10 is supposed to be optional upgrade (although there *are* numerous reports that some systems have been "upgraded" without the user's consent).  I apologize if somehow I am conveying that Windows 10 (or Windows itself) is mandatory, but I don't see that.  If you would like to discuss this further, we can discuss it in chat.

Comment: I was not meaning to invalidate your claims/concerns. My intent was to point out that answers to your question are most likely going to be subjective and opinion in nature, regardless of what you are interested in receiving. Again, if you add some citations to validate your claims, it may encourage factual answers. My comment about being "optional" was tongue-in-cheek. Sorry.

Comment: @CharlieRB Sorry I misinterpreted your tongue-in-cheekiness.  Humor and smiles can be hard to detect online! :-)

Comment: This is a tough question to ask here because basically, you're asking for a list.  Even if you word it in a way that no value judgements are needed to determine whether or not something is included, it is difficult to tell if or when the list is complete, so it's hard to tell a "right answer".  Some people might even object to a question asking for an official source of information on the subject.  A better shot might be researching the issue to find the lists from other sources, then ask technical questions about specifics.

Comment: you can stop automatic Updates with a small cool 3rd party tool: http://superuser.com/a/948069/174557

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thanks Andre!  I gave you a +1 over there.  Does it work on W10 **Home**, **Pro**, and **Enterprise**?

Comment: the tool works fine for my Pro test install, but it should work fine for Home, too.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thanks.  I wonder if it would *also* help the (possibly millions of) people who have trouble with Windows Update in Windows 7.

Comment: no, this tool relies on WU infrastructure and calls the same WU API to detect new updates. So it can't help to solve the Win7 slow scanning issue. I explained here why it is slow: http://superuser.com/a/1062876/174557

Comment: @magicandre1981 Makes sense.  Thanks for the details Andre!

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 Home Premium (and above) comes with Windows Media Center (WMC). You can't get it officially with Windows 10.

There are some, IMO, less important features missing too:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-win_upgrade/windows-10-and-windows-media-center/f75fafe8-89e6-42a8-8ebb-18c77a7e8fe7

Comment: Answers here are much better if they're self contained so people don't have to go chasing around other locations to see the information.  There's also a problem of links breaking.  Can you expand your answer to include the essential information, and use the link for attribution?

Comment: The question was "are there other real issues". I made a straight forward answer - Windows Media Center is missing from Windows 10. If you don't know what Windows Media Center is, you most likely won't care. The link is provides other list of feature which I don't see as "real issues" compare to WMC missing.

Comment: My comment applies to anything in a link.  If it's important enough to mention it, include the essential information here.  Aside from the post quality aspect, readers appreciate it and, in general, it will be reflected in how posts are viewed and rated.