# Windows Update Slow on Vista

Tags: windows, windows-vista, windows-update, malware

Update I was able to get Readiness Tool to run but not the update
Now the reediness tool will not even run
Security Essentials will run

I have legal Windows 7 to install
Do you think that is safe bet to try?

Had some performance issue so I ran MalwareBytes and Security Essentials.

It found some malware that was successfully removed.

I was able to Update Security Essentials and I ran it again for safety and it found nothing additions.

The last successful Windows Update was 5 days ago

Checking for Updates has been running 6 hours
CPU 100%  network 0%

Windows6.0-KB947821-v35-x86.mnu fails to install
It is supposed to be a tool to address update problems

I fear the registry got hacked to prevent updates

What can I do?

I know Vista.  I got it free.

Comment: "I know Vista. I got it free." You are running a pirated copy?

Comment: @DavidPostill No it is NOT pirated.

Comment: this is a known issue, MS fixed it in Win7 with the July 2016 update rollup, but never backported it to Vista.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Windows Update is slow because](https://superuser.com/a/1062876/174557) Windows needs to check if the updates are required or already replaced. Those calls are slow. For Windows 7 Microsoft fixed it with the [July 2016 update rollup](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3172605), but this was never backported to Vista.

To get updates faster for Vista, you [should use WSUSoffline](http://download.wsusoffline.net/). Start WSUSoffline (`UpdateGenerator.exe`), click on `Legacy` tab and select here Vista/Server 2008 for the correct CPU architecture (x86 or x64).

Comment: It's slow because it loops infinitely.  Can run for days and never end.